# Powershell запустить видео на форме

Tags: видео, powershell, forms

Подскажите пожалуйста как запустить видео на форме? С гифкой или картинкой проблем нет, а вот с видео вышли проблемы. Нашёл упоминание, что нужно использовать VideoDrawing а затем DrawingBrush. Но ума не приложу как всё собрать воедино. Вот код с гифкой, проблем нет, а как мне эту же гифку заменить на видео? Чтобы проигрывалось постоянно. Размеры у видео и у гифки одинаковые.

Update: 
Нашёл иное решение через WPF, попытался сделать чтобы видео проигрывалось постоянно - получилось, но видео почему-то обрезается, теряется последняя секунда. Как можно это побороть?

```
#WPF Library for Playing Movie and some components
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.ComponentModel
#XAML File of WPF as windows for playing movie
[xml]$XAML = @"

<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="PowerShell Video Player" Height="355" Width="560" ResizeMode="NoResize">
        <MediaElement Height="355" Width="553" Name="VideoPlayer" LoadedBehavior="Manual" />

</Window>
"@

#Movie Path
[uri]$VideoSource = "C:\Test.mp4"

#Divide All Objects on XAML
$XAMLReader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $XAML)
$Window=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $XAMLReader )
$VideoPlayer = $Window.FindName("VideoPlayer")


$timeline= New-Object System.Windows.Media.MediaTimeline $VideoSource

$timeline.RepeatBehavior='Forever'
$tclock=$timeline.CreateClock()


#Video Default Setting
$VideoPlayer.Source = $VideoSource;
#$VideoPlayer.Play()
$VideoPlayer.Clock=$tclock


#Show Up the Window 
$Window.ShowDialog() | out-null
```

Comment: Сейчас у вас используется WinForms. Эта технология не умеет проигрывать видео сама по себе, нужно размещать какой-либо компонент видеоплеера на форме. А `VideoDrawing` и `DrawingBrush` - компоненты WPF.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov благодарю за пояснение. После поиска ответа в гугле так и понял, что нужно использовать иное решение. В принципе нашёл, и даже сделал, но получились некоторые сложности.

Answer (score 1):

В общем нашёл решение, нужно было добавить обработчик событий и решать всё через WPF.

```
#WPF Library for Playing Movie and some components
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.ComponentModel
#XAML File of WPF as windows for playing movie
[xml]$XAML = @"

<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="PowerShell Video Player" Height="355" Width="560" ResizeMode="NoResize">
        <MediaElement Height="355" Width="553" Name="VideoPlayer" LoadedBehavior="manual" />

</Window>
"@

#Movie Path
[uri]$VideoSource = "C:\Test.mp4"

#Divide All Objects on XAML
$XAMLReader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $XAML)
$Window=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $XAMLReader )
$VideoPlayer = $Window.FindName("VideoPlayer")

#Video Default Setting
$VideoPlayer.Source = $VideoSource;

$VideoPlayer.Play()


$VideoPlayer.Add_MediaEnded({
$VideoPlayer.Stop()
$VideoPlayer.Play()
})

#Show Up the Window 
$Window.ShowDialog() | out-null
```